# Making Amazon DMS continuous replication work with changing IP address

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds, dms

I am new to Amazon DMS, just read and watched a couple of videos on how it works.

I'm thinking of this particular setup:

`On Premise Local Database -----> DMS -----> Amazon RDS`

On the Amazon DMS task setup page, it asks for my on-premise IP address. I enter the IP address and other information and it will presumably work. However my ISP renews lease and changes my IP every few days.

Question:

1. How do make sure the DMS task will continue to work even after my IP address gets changed? Is there a client/tool/whatever where the on premise computer can update the DMS settings to change the old IP address to the new IP address